# Questions about Drupal 8

Tags: discussion

This is prompted by [a recent question about Drupal 8](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30311/installation-of-devel-vers-8x-show-complete-different-behaviour-compared-to-d).  I am not talking about the merits of this question in particular (I do agree that it was not a good fit for DA), but how do we want to handle *good* questions about Drupal 8?

The biggest problem that I see is that D8 is still rather immature ([feature freeze will be EOY at the earliest](http://buytaert.net/drupal-8-feature-freeze-december-1st-2012)), so there is a good chance that questions may be influenced by bugs and/or things that are still in flux.

I think we should discourage D8 questions, but don't actively burninate them.

Personally, I won't be taking a serious look at D8 until next year, so I won't be answering any D8 questions.

This is the only related question on Meta.SO that I could find, [Is it okay to close questions about preview and beta products](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106265/is-it-okay-to-close-questions-about-preview-and-beta-products).

Thoughts?

Comment: +1 Totally agree. Nearly any question/answer about Drupal 8 would have to involve a fair amount of speculation, which would probably make it ineligible for this site anyway

Answer (score 5):

Agreed, before there is at least a beta version or something, the only valid answer for non-developers is what I wrote in that question IMHO.

For developers, I think questions will be valid much earlier, e.g. starting around the feature freeze, there will be a huge amount of changes that could be asked and can be answered by then.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the good questions about Drupal 8 are the ones that are still relevant when Drupal 8 will have its first official release. Generally, questions that involve speculation are not between them; they would not interest future readers, once Drupal comes out with a public release, nor would they interest any readers now, as there are few developers that need to get involved with developing modules for Drupal 8, now.

Answer (score 1):

I completely agree. Drupal SA is a QA site, not a discussion site. The proper channels for discussing Drupal 8 development are listed in the [Drupal 8 Initiatives](http://groups.drupal.org/drupal-initiatives) page.