# Questions about Drupal 8 core development

Tags: discussion

I appreciate this discussion is already kind of resolved over at [Questions about Drupal 8](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/906/questions-about-drupal-8), and possibly at [Questions about contrib/core developement](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/998/questions-about-contrib-core-developement) (although there wasn't much discussion there) but this question is slightly more specific.

There was a question tackled by MPD and Letharion ([Creating Drupal 8 route for AJAX requests](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/55303/creating-drupal-8-route-for-ajax-requests)) asking for help in creating a Drupal 8 core patch.  Surely these kind of questions/discussions should be in the relevant issues in the issue queue for D8 core?

Long story short, should we be helping Drupal 8 core development here?

Comment: First off, I want to point out that the question itself doesn't really concern core development. The author wants to make a patch, yes, but the question is really about how the routing system works in D8, which can be answered without regard to D8 core development issues.

Comment: @Letharion Fair point, but there are at least 2 other applicable close reasons for this question

Comment: Yeah, I'm really in favour of closing and suggestion the core queue. I'm mostly playing the devils advocate here, and/or make sure we close the question for the right reasons.

Comment: @Letharion I apologise, I probably could have worded my question a bit better - that's what happens when you type with a sandwich in your hand ;-) Please feel free to edit the question if you think it can be worded more efficiently!

Comment: @Letharion Always a fun game to play :)

Comment: @Letharion I'll give it a little while for more comments on this, but I was literally just about to close it anyway when I saw the link to this discussion. Unless it's improved it doesn't meet the quality standard anyway, from a couple of perspectives, so it will be closed

Comment: @Chapabu, nah, I think it's fine. :) I'm just saying there may be a different question we should also be asking, but then again everyone (except MPD?) seems to be in agreement that the Q should be closed anyway.

Comment: @Letharion Phew, I was worried I'd offended you ;-) I'll leave this question open for a while anyway to let other people (MPD?) weigh in :)

Comment: I'm the lenient mod :)  I think @kiamlaluno's edit gives it more focus, and think the question should remain open.  I am going to cleanup the comments later today if nobody objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is specific about Drupal 8, as Drupal extends many Symfony classes. Using Symfony with Drupal 8 means knowing which those classes are, and what those classes do.

The criteria I would use for considering acceptable the question in question are:

- Is the question about a part of Drupal 8 that is stable enough, and not subject to any further change?
- Is the question specific for Drupal 8, or would similar code be useful for third-party modules too?

Even in the case the question is asked to provide a patch for Drupal (whatever it is for Drupal 7, or Drupal 8), the code that is used could be useful to write a custom module, or a module that is hosted on Drupal.org. The way Drupal core code is written should be possibly used as guide to write third-party modules.

The question should not be seen simply as a question about writing a patch, but a question about writing code; if the code, or how the code is written, is helpful to future readers, then the question should not be closed, provided that the criteria I shortly exposed before are valid.

Comment: Marking this one as correct based on the proposed criteria.  I guess the actual answer is on a per-question basis though?

Comment: That is correct: The fact a question about Drupal 8 is closed cannot be used as evidence to ask another Drupal 8 question is closed too.

Answer (score 3):

That particular question, I asked him to file it and I do not know the answer. My understanding is routes are somewhat finished and even though it's for a core issue this is relevant for contrib as well. If noone here can answer it I will try to get the WSCCI people to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

In my personal opinion, questions about core development need to be left in the relevant issue for Drupal core in case a consensus changes.  Core changes can be monitored quite closely, and the people who monitor may not come here.

In fact, I've only seen Chx recently - I don't think any other D8 heavy hitters frequent Drupal Answers.

Comment: I agree 100%, but with with the "question in question", this statement doesn't necessarily have to be relevant.

Comment: Oh the irony, chx has just asked a question! Quick, corner him and ask him the answer to the routing issue ;)

Comment: I think tim.plunkett is pretty involved with D8 right now, esp with integrating views in core.

Answer (score 1):

> Surely these kind of questions/discussions should be in the relevant issues in the issue queue for D8 core?

Yes, 100%. The fact that it's regarding Drupal 8 is actually irrelevant in this case, if the question was exactly the same (asking about the architecture of a particular sub-system in order to provide a patch to core) but for Drupal 7, it would *still* be off topic (interesting though it is).

Also it's essentially a tutorial request, there's no mention of research effort having been put in, or what the OP has already tried themselves.

It could be closed for several reasons, ironically its relation to Drupal 8 probably isn't one of those.